# Is there any way to timeout slow queries on application server

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, tomcat

I am using MySQL DB and spring boot 2.0.0 deployed on tomcat server, is there any way I can timeout slow queries from my application server.

Comment: I'm not sure about how to timeout slow queries from application server. But it's manipulable  in MySQL. Try the system variable `MAX_EXECUTION_TIME` .

Comment: What version of MySQL?  See also MariaDB.

Comment: You may find this URL useful, it has references to both MariaDB and MySQL options.  https://mariadb.com/kb/en/aborting-statements/
  Look twice before you leap into this part of the world.  Do NOT forget there are sometimes pauses especially when buffer pool dirty pages are processing to storage media.

Comment: Short answer is Yes for MySQL db.  Review ALL max_? Global Variables.

Answer (score 0):

In hikari Connection Pool there is a property - maxLifetimeMs which you can manipulate in two different ways:

1. Adding values in property file :

> ```
> spring:
>     hikari:
>          max-lifetime: 840000
> ```

2. Changing in the config :

> ```
>    final HikariDataSource dataSource;  
>    config.setMaxLifetime(840000);
> ```

This will have set the maximum time taken out by a query. No query can run beyond the duration set by you.

For identification of slow query you need to integrate any APM tool with your application server